# Placeholder text for password doesn't fit the input on “Edit your profile” page on Russian Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, user-interface, localization, russian-stackoverflow, profile-edit

On en SO:

> [image]

On ru SO:

> [image]

Comment: de.stackoverflow.com is gonna kill the ux folks.